# Allow part of a type

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like this

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

and a method like this

```
updateUser(user: User) {
}
```

If typed as written `updateUser` can't be passed just a name (`updateUser({name: 'Anna'}` fails), if that's the only property I want to update.

If I make `email` optional on `User` it's possible, but I don't want that. If someone gets passed a User they should be able to expect that field.
I can also type `updateUser` as

```
updateUser(user: {name?: string, email?: string}) {
}
```

and it would work, but I have to repeat the whole user and update both places when `User` gains new properties.

Is there a way to specify `updateUser` so that it allows parts of a user object but fails if someone try to pass missing or wrongly typed properties?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we can always use assertion - `<User>` - like this :

```
updateUser(<User>{name: 'Anna'})
updateUser(<User>{email: 'some@anna.com'})
```

But that is in fact not the best way, because anything will pass through that way:

```
updateUser(<User>{wrongProperty: 'wrong'})
```

So, I would really rather go with nullability

```
interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}
```

And with typescript 1.6 we can be sure that  this will pass

```
interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}

function updateUser2(user: IUser) {
}
// these are of type IUser
updateUser2({name: 'Anna'})
updateUser2({email: 'some@anna.com'})
```

while this not:

```
// this is not IUser
updateUser2({wrongProperty: 'someValue'})
```

Check it here, at [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20email%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20updateUser(user%3A%20User)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0AupdateUser(%3CUser%3E%7Bname%3A%20'Anna'%7D)%0AupdateUser(%3CUser%3E%7Bemail%3A%20'some%40anna.com'%7D)%0A%0A%0Ainterface%20IUser%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20email%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20updateUser2(user%3A%20IUser)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0AupdateUser2(%7Bname%3A%20'Anna'%7D)%0AupdateUser2(%7Bemail%3A%20'some%40anna.com'%7D)%0AupdateUser2(%7BwrongProperty%3A%20'someValue'%7D))

Also: [What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks)

> #### Stricter object literal assignment checks
>
> TypeScript 1.6 enforces stricter object literal assignment checks for the purpose of catching excess or misspelled properties. Specifically, when a fresh object literal is assigned to a variable or passed for a parameter of a non-empty target type, it is an error for the object literal to specify properties that don't exist in the target type.
>   Examples

```
var x: { foo: number };
x = { foo: 1, baz: 2 };  // Error, excess property `baz`

var y: { foo: number, bar?: number };
y = { foo: 1, baz: 2 };  // Error, excess or misspelled property `baz`
```